# What happens to destroyed districts in Citadels?

Tags: citadels

In Citadels when you destroy someone's district with the warlord it isn't clear what you do with the card. Does it return to the bottom of the district deck? This is the only other place district cards seem to go, other than player's hands and being in play.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems **Fantasy Flight Games has never officially ruled on this**, even though the question has been asked multiple times since the release of the game. However, there have been discussions from players about where the district card goes.

### Board Game Geek

In this forum on [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/378000/where-do-the-districts-destroyed-by-the-warlord-go) most people seem to agree that "Discarded/destroyed cards go to the bottom of the District (draw) deck." There is one person who says that they play with a discard pile, although a discard pile is never mentioned in the official rules.

Also on [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/711845/ive-reworded-all-cards-to-prevent-ambiguity-in-the), a user rewrote the character cards to "prevent ambiguity." He added this line to the Warlord:

> Place the destroyed district to the bottom of the District Deck face-down.

If you scroll down through the comments, nobody challenges this even though there is discussion about some of the other reworded character cards.

The third place on BGG where this sentiment can be found is [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/162856/discarding-in-citadels). About halfway down, user Mark Biggar notes that cards destroyed by the Warlord are "discarded" to the bottom of the District deck. There is no dissension on this thread, either.

### Fantasy Flight Games Forums

The other place I could find any mention of this was on the [FFG Forums](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_discusion.asp?efid=51&efcid=1&efidt=207077). This thread is pretty bad. It has this badly worded question (emphasis mine):

> If the Warlord destroys one of your districts does it go back into your hand or at *the bottom of the discard pile*?

This is accompanied by a comment that doesn't really address the OP's question. This doesn't seem to really help with deciding where the destroyed district goes.

### Conclusion

The consensus from BGG seems to be **districts destroyed by the Warlord go to the bottom of the District deck.** I'd go with this as the answer to your question.

Comment: Does the District deck ever get exhausted in a normal game of Citadels?  I can't really remember it doing so, which makes me think the question may be rather academic...

Comment: @thesunneversets I've seen it happen in a 7-player game, but it isn't really that common. I suppose with the right districts in play, players may end up digging through more cards when drawing. And realistically, the Warlord isn't destroying a large amount of districts every game. So you're probably right; it is rare that recycling destroyed districts would even have a serious impact on the game.

Comment: Since the magician lets you return your hand to draw a hand of the same size, if you want one of the rare purple cards which gains you victory points equal to the number of cards in your hand, you could spend all your turns drawing 1, exchanging until you find it! Not saying its a good tactic, just that drawing an ever increasing number of cards a turn would quickly get through the deck!

Comment: @Nick if you continuously take the Magician you are bound to be murdered, robbed or worse before you can pull of that trick! :) Welcome to Citadels.

Answer (score 2):

The rules/cards always say to put cards back at the bottom of the draw pile. Chances of actually seeing those cards again in a single game are extremely rare. There may be one card that lets you look through the draw pile, hence, you should be able to find any cards put back there. Since the rules never mention any other piles, that means you cannot create your own piles (and in this case, a discard pile). So the debate would be if you destroy a card, does it go to the bottom of the draw pile or the box (and out of the game completely)? And with that, the general consensus and common method of play is to put the card underneath the draw pile.